# Joomla Facebook plugin using onContentAfterSave trigger not working

Tags: php, facebook, joomla

I have checked that this trigger is functioning by putting a `die('test')` statement on the first line of the `onContentAfterSave()` function. I am wondering why the rest of the code inside is not working.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die ('Access Deny');

class plgContentMypost extends JPlugin {

    public function onContentAfterSave( $context, $article, $isNew  )
    {
    require_once JPATH_ROOT  . '/plugins/content/mypost/src/facebook.php';

        $appId = '233015226851759';
        $secret = '95daba36aa48679229e';
        $returnurl = 'http://localhost/sample/examples';
        $permissions = 'manage_pages, publish_stream, publish_actions';

        // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
        $fb = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $appId,
          'secret' => $secret,

        ));

        $access_token = $fb->getAccessToken();
        $name = 'LUPIN'; 
        $message = 'this is a message'; 
        $description = 'this is my description';
        $pictureUrl = 'http://rofi.philfire.com.ph/joomla16/images/iphone-4-top-new-1.jpg';
        $link = 'http://rofi.philfire.com.ph/joomla16/'; 

        $attachment =  array(
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'message' => "$message",
            'name' => "$name",
            'description' => "$description",
            'link' => "$link",
            'picture' => "$pictureUrl",
            // 'actions' => array('name'=>'Try it now', 'link' => "$appUrl")
        );

        $post_id = $fb->api("me/feed","POST",$attachment);

    }

}
```

If I use this code as a standalone, it works fine and posts the contents on Facebook.

```
require_once '/src/facebook.php';

$appId = '233015226851759';
$secret = '95daba36aa48679229e';
$returnurl = 'http://localhost/sample/examples';
$permissions = 'manage_pages, publish_stream, publish_actions';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appId,
    'secret' => $secret,      
));

$access_token = $fb->getAccessToken();
$name = 'LUPIN'; 
$message = 'this is a message'; 
$description = 'this is my description';
$pictureUrl = 'http://rofi.philfire.com.ph/joomla16/images/iphone-4-top-new-1.jpg';
$link = 'http://rofi.philfire.com.ph/joomla16/'; 

$attachment =  array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => "$message",
    'name' => "$name",
    'description' => "$description",
    'link' => "$link",
    'picture' => "$pictureUrl",
    // 'actions' => array('name'=>'Try it now', 'link' => "$appUrl")
);

$post_id = $fb->api("me/feed","POST",$attachment);
```

below is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<extension type="plugin" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade" group="content">
    <name>My Post</name>
    <author>Mark Orosa</author>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>This is My FB Post Plugin</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="mypost">mypost.php</filename>
        <folder>src</folder>
        <filename>mypost.xml</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <config></config>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an incorrect file path on the require_once. The src directory is located under /path_to_your_install/plugins/content/mypost

So you better try with something like this:

```
require_once JPATH_ROOT . '/plugins/content/mypost/src/facebook.php'
```

Check for the right JPATH constant to use here http://docs.joomla.org/Constants

Maybe this http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla could help you too.

Regards!

Comment: hi, pep, thank you for answering, i tried what you have suggested, made sure i had the right PATH to access facebook.php, but it would seem that joomla is still not letting me execute this line:                `$post_id = $fb->api("me/feed","POST",$attachment);`

Comment: i also added `return true;` before closing the function, as the suggested syntax from the link you given. i am now getting, `Save failed with the following error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`, trying to work on it about well over an hour now.

Comment: If you are posting a form a security token is needed. You could add one using **echo JHtml::_('form.token');** inside your form.